# Javascript canvas: animate box on touch, view only borders

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to do a simple animation with html5. Please take a look at the link below, through a touch screen device.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41627/wipe.html

The problem is as follows : Every time the user touches the screen , a box gets drawn around his finger which animates from small to big. I want just the outer most boundary to be visible and not the rest. I do not want to clear the canvas as I want the state of the rest of the canvas to be preserved.

Images to illustrate the issue:
[image: Initial Screen]
[image: Attempting to draw the box]
My code is as follows :

```
    function init() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var img = document.createElement('IMG');

        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            ctx.closePath();    
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';    
        }

        img.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41627/6.jpg";

        function drawPoint(pointX,pointY){
            var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(pointX, pointY, 0, pointX, pointY, 30);
            grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,255,.6)"); 
            grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent"); 
            ctx.fillStyle = grd;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pointX,pointY,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;
        function boxAround(pointX,pointY, a, b) {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; 
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.strokeRect(pointX-a, pointY-b, (2*a), (2*b));
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';  
            if(a < 100) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    boxAround(pointX,pointY, a+5, b+5);
                }, 20); 
            }

        }

        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
            drawPoint(e.touches[0].screenX,e.touches[0].screenY);
            boxAround(e.touches[0].screenX,e.touches[0].screenY,0 , 0);

        },false);

        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            drawPoint(e.touches[0].screenX,e.touches[0].screenY);
        },false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by either using a second canvas, or even just having the box be a plain `<div>` element that is positioned over the canvas. Otherwise, there is no way around redrawing your canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you provide some hints on how to implement this. I am new to this, would appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, you already have code to get the touch position, you can use this to adjust a `<div>`'s `absolute` position on the page and either animate the size yourself or let a CSS `animation/@keyframes` do it for you. There's plenty of info on these things on the 'net.